# Reversing date conversion using specific format in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I convert the date to a string so that I can use it for various grouping related work. However in certain groupings the reverse conversion fails.

```
db.test.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        date: "$date",
        grouped_format: {
            "$dateToString": {
                date: '$date',
                format: "%Y-%m",
                timezone: 'Europe/London',
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        converted: {
            "$dateFromString": {
                dateString: '$grouped_format',
                format: "%Y-%m", // if i comment this out, it works, 
                timezone: 'Europe/London',
                
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The error I get is

```
{
    "message" : "an incomplete date/time string has been found, with elements missing: '2016-01'",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 241,
    "codeName" : "ConversionFailure",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

If I comment the `format` under `$dateFromString`, I get the desired result.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60ca299f10949130abbe5c8e"),
    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "grouped_format" : "2014-04",
    "converted" : ISODate("2014-03-31T23:00:00.000Z") // London is one hour ahead due to DST so this is correct. -> start of the month
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60ca2aaf10949130abbe5c8f"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "grouped_format" : "2021-01",
    "converted" : ISODate("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") // London is even with UTC so this is correct. -> start of the month
}
```

Unfortunately, I want to be able to specify any custom format in `$dateToString` and have it be converted back.

As an example, if the custom format is `"%G-%V"`which is the ISO week year and ISO week number, specifying the format in `$dateToString` and `$dateFromString` works correctly.

I've tried the following formats and here are the results. As you can see, the No. `4.` in the table does not specify the minute but it still works fine. However any variation of the date from No.`6.` to `8.` fails.
If I can't reliably reverse the value then I will need to create a special function that covers all edge cases but to do that I need to understand why this is happening in the first place.

| No | Format | Works/Fails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L' | Works |
| 2 | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M' | Works |
| 3 | '%Y-%m-%dT%H' | Works |
| 4 | '%Y-%m-%d' | Works |
| 5 | '%G-%V' | Works |
| 6 | '%Y-%m' | Fails |
| 7 | '%Y-%m-01' | Fails |
| 8 | '%Y-%m-00' | Fails |

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#definition), the default formatter is "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ" but specifying it explicitly also does not work and errors out. No string or null/undefined value seems to work while converting "%Y-%m" unless you omit the format string entirely in `$dateFromString`. This makes the behaviour very strange.

Comment: Can't test right now, but would `{$concat: ['$grouped_format', '-01']}` work as the `dateString` parameter? If not, perhaps do `$concat` in an additional aggregation step before `$dateFromString`?

Comment: It won't work unless I also change the $dateFromString to `'%Y-%m-%d'` which I find strange. The concat step is akin to having `'%Y-%m-01'` in the `$dateToString` and it only works if I also change the `$dateFromString` to `'%Y-%m-%d'` but now the strings are not reversible.

Comment: Maybe [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/) will work better in your case. Then you don't have to convert date to string back and forth.